# bus error 10 - char * array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, bus

I write the following c++ code :

```
int main() {
     char *argv[4];
     cin >> argv[0] >> argv[1] >> argv[2] >> argv[3];
     cout << argv[0] << argv[1] << argv[2] << argv[3] << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

This gives me a segmentation fault 11. But If I initialise the array with 4 `string` values instead of taking user input and then print, it works fine.

Also, If I try the following :

```
int main() {
    char *argv[4] = {"bg","demo","running","2"};
    cout << argv[0] << argv[1] << argv[2] << argv[3] << endl;
    cin >> argv[0] >> argv[1] >> argv[2] >> argv[3];
    cout << argv[0] << argv[1] << argv[2] << argv[3] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get bus error 10. Kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong. I don't see any illegal memory accesses.

Comment: Literal strings aren't writable. You're trying to overwrite them when you do `cin >> argv[0]`

Comment: Have you consider using `std::string argv[4]` ? Make life easier.

Comment: And if the user enters words longer than those initial values, you'll write out of bounds. Why aren't you using `std::string` instead of `char*`?

Comment: @Barmar  and Chen OT  I have to pass the array to execvp later, and that function needs a char* array

Comment: @Sim You can use `.c_str()` to get a `char*` array from `std::string`

Comment: @Barmar and anyway this doesn't explain the first code's erroe

Comment: @Sim I thought you understood the first code's error, and just wanted an explanation for the second one. The first code's error is that you're trying to indirect through uninitialized pointers.

Comment: " don't see any illegal memory accesses"  - after `char *argv[4];     cin>>argv[0]`, where in memory do you think the characters are stored?

Comment: Also, the second code is an error since 2011  (string literal can no longer be implicitly converted to non-const `char *`)

Comment: @M.M Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The `argv[i]` of `char* argv[4];` is only a pointer to nowhere.

You need to prepare/allocate the space for input string writing, and let the `argv[i]` point to.

Methods like the following:

**Fixed length**

Space is allocated at stack. Fast but the length must be decided at compile time.

```
#define STR_SIZE 260
char argv[4][STR_SIZE];
```

**Dynamic length**

Space is in the heap. Memory allocation on heap operation is slower, but its length can be adjusted at runtime.

```
char* argv[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    argv[i] = new char[can_be_decided_at_runtime];
```

**C++ way**

Let the `std::string` handle the allocation for you.

```
std::string argv[4];
// Then use argv[i].c_str(); to get inner const char* pointer.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) instead of `char*`, since you are writing C++ and not C; you can use the [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method if you need to convert from `std::string` to `char*` for C functions.

In the first case you have to reserve memory for your strings like this:

```
int main()
{
    char *argv[4];
    //reserve 10 bytes for each char*
    argv[0] = new char[10];
    argv[1] = new char[10];
    argv[2] = new char[10];
    argv[3] = new char[10];
    cin>>argv[0]>>argv[1]>>argv[2]>>argv[3];
    cout<<argv[0]<<argv[1]<<argv[2]<<argv[3]<<endl;
    //free each char* to prevent memory leaks
    delete[] argv[0];
    delete[] argv[1];
    delete[] argv[2];
    delete[] argv[3];

    return 0;
}
```

To write the same code using `std::string`, you would have something like the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::string argv[4];
    cin>>argv[0]>>argv[1]>>argv[2]>>argv[3];
    cout<<argv[0]<<argv[1]<<argv[2]<<argv[3]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works :)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Ty [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

```
char *argv[4];
```

This argv char currently points to addresses that are not from the scope of your application.

You have to initialize every single argv to a given length

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    argv[i] = new char[2];
```

But keep in mind that you really have to be sure about the lenght of every argument that you will write into the console.

```
new char[2]
```

is only sufficient if you type

```
a b c d
```

into the console!

Otherwise you will have to write a function that processes the indefinite input length.
Another way is to use std::string's [.c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method, that returns const char*

Comment: `char[1]` isn't even sufficient for 1 character, you need space for the null terminator.